# Dangerously closely antonyms

Tags: spelling, antonyms

We have a tag "pseudo-antonym" here ("flammable" vs. "inflammable", "get up" vs. "get down"), but I ask for the exact opposite.

A classic is "He worked hard" vs. "He worked hardly". Also, make friends at a funeral fast by confusing "terrible" with "terrific" and "awful" with "awesome".

What's the technical name (so I can google it myself, but feel free to add more blatant examples as comment)? Pseudo homonym? "Homonym" isn't even a valid tag here...

Comment: like wise man and wise guy? XD

Comment: I don't think "pseudo-antonym" is a standard technical term.  I think it is something an questioner made up.  This question on [english.se] https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/542993/are-there-any-pairs-of-english-words-that-are-cognate-to-each-other-yet-have-opp didn't find a technical name for what you describe - but your examples could be the basis of an answer to that question.

Comment: And then there are self-antonyms(?) such as the old use of "cleave", to cling, and the current usage, to cut. Does "oversight" mean careful supervision, or ignoring something? Interestingly, in both Hebrew and in English, "to dust" can mean to sift dust onto something, as in disclosing fingerprints, or to clean dust from something. See "contranym", https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/650281/win-delorean-dmc-12-car-back-to-the-future?utm_content=infinitescroll1

Comment: We would say _He hardly worked_ rather than _he worked hardly_.

Comment: @JamesK: THX for the link! Now I remember: when I was young, I thought a fiend (specifically a Rarebit Fiend - Winsor McCay) was a sort of friend.

Comment: At least your examples are actually different words.  One word is "scan": it means "look over quickly to glean a summary" or it might mean "look at in detail with great care".  Very confusing.

Comment: A few of your examples are words that are in the process of changing meaning.  "Terrific" used to be a neutral or even negative word ("a terrific storm rose up"), but now it has a very positive connotation ("the weather today is terrific").  Same with "awesome": it used to mean "causing awe" but now it means "very good".

Answer (score 2):

When a word is its own opposite (or close to it), it is an [**Auto-antonym**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) or **contronym**. Examples include

> *Cleave*: 'to cut apart' **or** 'to bind together' 
> *Dust*: 'to remove dust' **or** 'to add dust' 
> *Fast*: 'without moving' **or** 'moving quickly' 
> *Peruse*: 'look over carefully and in detail' **or** 'skim' 
> *Sanction*: 'to approve' **or** 'to penalize' 
> *Sound off*: 'to yell' **or** 'to turn [the] sound off'

Sometimes two words which sound the same (i.e. which are homophones) have opposite meanings. These may be called **Antonymic homophones** or **homophonic antonyms**, but there is no standard term. It may also depend on accent. These may or may not include Auto-antonyms. (Non-auto-antonymic) examples include

> *raise* **and** *raze*: 'to build' **and** 'to destroy' 
> *resign* **and** *re-sign*: 'to quit' **and** 'to remain employed' 
> [in some British accents] *hypertension* **and** *hypotension*: 'overtense' **and** 'undertense'

Then there are words or phrases that sound very similar and mean different things. These can probably be classed as [**Mondegreens**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) or puns. It's hard to find good examples of these but here's a few

> *seize* **or** *ease*: 'to tense up' **and** 'to relax' 
> She likes being *chased* **or** *chaste*: 'promiscuous' **or** 'sexualy abstinent' 
> *innumerable* **or** *enumerable*: 'too many to be counted' **or** 'countable'  
> *road vehicle* **or** *rowed vehicle*: 'land-based vehicle' **or** 'oared marine vehicle'